# Abstract class with two constructors c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

Suppose that I have the following Abstract class with 2 constructors:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTCLASS_H
#define ABSTRACTCLASS_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class AbstractClass
{
    public:
      AbstractClass(int);
      AbstractClass();
      virtual ~AbstractContext();
      //Pure virtual function
      virtual void doSomething() = 0;

    private:
        int  x;
};

#endif
```

---

I have 2 classes That will inherit from `AbstractClass`.

1. Class A will use `AbstractClass(int);`
2. Class B Will use `AbstractClass();`

---

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A: public AbstractClass
{
    public:
     A(int = 0);
     virtual ~A();
     virtual void doSomething();
    private:
     int xCoord;
}

#endif

A.cpp
#include "A.H"
A::A(int x):AbstractClass(x),xCoord(x) {}

void A::doSomething()
{
  cout << xCoord * xCoord << endl;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H
        
    class B: public AbstractClass
    {
        public:
         B();
         virtual ~B();
         virtual void doSomething();
    }
    
    #endif

    B.cpp
    #include "B.H"
    B::B():AbstractClass() {}
    
    void B::doSomething()
    {
      cout << "nothing" << endl;
    }
```

---

## Question

- I using 2 constructors in an abstract class a good practice?
- Is the inheritence correct? especially that i am using 2 versions of the constructor?

Comment: You can't initialize `xCoord` in the `A` initialization list as it's a private member variable. I suspect you want to pass `x` to `AbstractClass` and have it initialize `xCoord` for you.

Comment: Also, `A::doSomething` cannot access `xCoord` as it's private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally appropriate to have an ABC with more than one `public` constructor if both of those constructors can be applied to every type that is (or will be one day) derived from the ABC.

That is to say, `public` base class constructors are still part of the interface of the class.  If one or more of these constructors are not applicable to *every* concrete instantiation, then ideally they should not be part of the `public` interface.  Making those special constructors `private` is an improvement because it becomes more difficult for future programmers to implement a new concrete derived type incorrectly.

This is when other creational patterns come in to play.  One common and simple method is to provide `static` member functions on the ABC to create the concrete types.  This is an example of the [factory method](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Factory) pattern.

```
class A;
class B;

class AbstractClass 
{
public:
  static std::unique_ptr <AbstractClass> MakeA (int x)
  { 
    return std::make_unique <A> (x);  // You need to provide this, easily found
  }

  static std::unique_ptr <AbstractClass> MakeB ()
  {
    return std::m,ake_unique <B> ();
  }
  virtual ~AbstractClass();

private:
  AbstractClass ();
  AbstractClass (int x);
};
```

There are [many other](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Creational_Patterns) creational patterns; this is just the most intuitive in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this.

Your base class has two ways to initialize itself, and the derived classes use the one most appropriate to their implementation. Likewise they could choose to provide two constructors of their own that map down to the constructors in the base class.

The key thing is that both constructors should leave the class in a sensible state. So, for example, your default constructor in the base class should probably set `xCoord` to some sensible value (probably 0), whilst I'm guessing that `AbstractClass(int)` is setting `xCoord` to the value passed to the constructor.

Comment: if I understood correctly I should initialize xCoord like this? `A(int = 0);` @Sean

Comment: That's not just initializing. It's allowing creation of A with empty c'tor that will run as if 0 was passed to A (apart from the creation of A with an integer argument).

Comment: @HaniGoc - That would declare a constructor which has a parameter with a default value of 0. It's usually good practice to name the parameters in the header so you'd need to say `A(int x=0)` and then in the implementation say `A::A(int x) : AbstractClass(x) {}`